# Convolution of polynomials returns unexpected value

Tags: r, floating-point, rounding, fft, convolution

I'm using R 3.6.2 (platform = x86_64-w64-mingw32)

In the convolution of the following two polynomial coefficient vectors, I would expect the first entry to be exactly 1.0, but the `convolve` function differs:

```
g <- c(1, -49, 1155, -17441, 189700, -1583071, 10545901, -57608692, 
263063351, -1018546561, 3380085631, -9693547553, 24176423345, 
-52691112850)
u <- c(1, -6, 11, -6)
convolve(g, rev(u), type = 'o')
# output
 [1]  1.000172e+00 -5.500020e+01  1.460000e+03 -2.491600e+04
 [5]  3.073450e+05 -2.920052e+06  2.223567e+07 -1.394361e+08
 [9]  7.342188e+08 -3.293898e+09  1.273071e+10 -4.275645e+10
[13]  1.256299e+11 -3.246592e+11  6.402486e+11 -7.246608e+11
[17]  3.161467e+11
```

Note that the first entry in the result is 1.000172, not 1.0.

Performing the same convolution in Python 3.7.4 delivers the expected answer:

```
import numpy as np
g = [1, -49, 1155, -17441, 189700, -1583071, 10545901, -57608692, 263063351, -1018546561, 3380085631, -9693547553, 24176423345, -52691112850]
u = [1, -6, 11, -6]
np.convolve(g,u)
array([            1,           -55,          1460,        -24916,
              307345,      -2920052,      22235673,    -139436079,
           734218840,   -3293897685,   12730714010,  -42756453616,
        125629929970, -324659189789,  640248619213, -724660781420,
        316146677100], dtype=int64)
```

Also when I use the `convolveCpp` example from the [Rcpp vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf), I get the same results as in the Python above.

Is there a rounding or precision issue with `convolve` or the underlying `fft`?

Comment: It's the `fft` that's approximate. In Python, `from scipy import signal` `signal.fftconvolve(g, u)` gives an approximate answer as well, and it also uses `fft`.

Comment: OP's example is valid, but the magnitude of the coefficients obscures the problem. Just `convolve(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), type="open")` is enough to show that the result of `convolve` is not the same as polynomial convolution -- `convolve` returns `c(4, 11, 6)` while polynomial convolution (as implemented, e.g., by `pracma::conv`) returns `c(3, 10, 8)`.

Comment: @RobertDodier Convolution of the sequences [1,2] and [3,4] is supposed to return [3,10,8]. I don't know why your `convolve` returns [4,11,6], if this is R, it support's OP's problem with that function. Maybe R's `convolve` is broken.

Comment: Well, I'm muddying the waters; I think OP's problem is indeed with numerical precision. On re-reading the problem statement more carefully, I see it says `convolve(g, rev(u), type="o")` (i.e., reversing `u`) which, it turns out, yields polynomial convolution, while `convolve(g, u, type="o")` is something else (maybe more like a correlation than a convolution). That seems like an ill-chosen default, but OP seems to be aware of it, so my comments aren't helping.

Comment: I see now, re-reading `? convolve`, that it says `Note that the usual definition of convolution of two sequences ‘x’ and ‘y’ is given by ‘convolve(x, rev(y), type = "o")’.` Yet again I was not sufficiently enlightened to read the documentation ... I still think that's a very poorly chosen default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [R `convolve` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/convolve) indeed uses the FFT in its computations.
If I replicate your experiment in MATLAB, using the FFT, I also get an inexact result:

```matlab
format long

g = [1, -49, 1155, -17441, 189700, -1583071, 10545901, -57608692, ...
263063351, -1018546561, 3380085631, -9693547553, 24176423345, -52691112850];
u = [1, -6, 11, -6];
r = ifft(fft([g,zeros(1,numel(u)-1)]) .* fft(up[u,zeros(1,numel(g)-1)]);
```

Here the first value, `r(1)` is `0.999971277573529`. This value is an order of magnitude closer to 1 than the result of `convolve` in R. If R uses a lesser implementation of the FFT, it is very likely that the difference you see is solely due to numerical imprecision in the FFT.

Do note that if I convert the inputs to single precision floats, `r(1)` becomes `4.6261e+04`, meaning that this particular problem does require a high degree of precision to avoid catastrophic errors.

---

Python's `np.convolve`, much like MATLAB's `conv`, does not use the FFT in its computations, and hence is able to produce exact results.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just wondering if there's a case for `convolve` to be made more accurate in base R. After all, it's a fairly commonly used procedure. If I'm not wrong, the reason to use `fft` inside the convolution is that its algorithmic complexity is better than the `O(n^2)` of the naive (but more accurate) approach?

Comment: @user2474226: You have values in your input signal that are 10 orders of magnitude apart. This is not at all common in most uses of `convolve`. However, the FFT method is more efficient than the direct implementation only for large signals. With few values as in this case, there is no time advantage (and probably a time disadvantage) to using the FFT. R should really try to provide both methods of computation so the user can select which is the more appropriate one in each case.

Comment: @RobertDodier "Polynomial convolution" is not a thing. Convolution of the factors of two polynomials produces the factors of the product of the two polynomials. That is the same convolution as everyone is talking about on this page.

Comment: I just mean convolution yielding the same coefficients as if one were multiplying polynomials. I agree that's the convolution that most people mean when they talk about convolution, but, unhelpfully, it is not the default behavior of R's `convolve` function. FWIW.